# iPhone: how to change label font-size by autosizing it for iPad app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, uilabel

I want to convert an iPhone app into an iPad app

For that I am autosizing the controls, for button it works fine.

Problem comes when I am Autosizimg the label the position of label changes relatively but the font size of label remains same.

How to increase the label size (i.e. font size of label) by Autosizing label ?

Please Help & Suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dynamically added the check for whether the device is iPhone or iPad and set the font size of label text according to the current device

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        //Code for iPad
    else
        //Code for iPhone or iPod

Comment: That was the only solution i found as well, however i used the ? operator and a class: [Device isIpad] ? 88 : 44 and then once i realized i was always increasing the font by the same amount: [Device fontScale] * 44.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to chose a very large default font size, and set

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

This will work for a single-line label.  For multiline, you will need to do more.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Hey but I dont want to set a large font size as default. Is there any other option where we can scale the font size according to autosizing of labels?